# How to export an async function inside a router in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following route in index.js file-

```
router.post(/login, async (req,res) => {
async function getUser(id, data){
... Some logic
}
})
```

How can I export this function so that I can import it and call from another file i.e. register.js which has it's own route.?
Tried module.exports = getUser()
But it says it's not defined.

Comment: If you're trying to get access to `res` from outside this module and route by calling `getUser()` (which your comment below implies), then that doesn't really make sense.  A route is a temporal thing.  It's only active for a short amount of time during a specific request.  You shouldn't be attempting to call some function later to get access to the `res` object.  That was only useful during the running of the route and then it's done.  So, you need to back up and describe what problem you're really trying to solve.  What is this other function trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try defining the function outside the router handler function

```js
async function getUser(id, data){
... Some logic
}

router.post(/login, async (req,res) => {
  // getUser should be accessible inside here
})

module.exports = getUser
```

To accommodate your comment/edit where you mentioned that getUser will adapt the incoming res data to be exported, we need to define a state object outside the getUser function. At least from a functional perspective this will work, but I believe there are better ways to tidy this:

```js
let state = {}

async function getUser(id, data){
// Some logic
// use res here by accessing the state object
}

router.post(/login, async (req,res) => {
  // getUser should be accessible inside here
  state = res;
})

module.exports = getUser
```

Comment: But the getUser function returns the res which is part of /login route, if I take it outside, res becomes undefined.

Comment: are you saying that res will be part of the getUser function that gets exported out?

Comment: perhaps you can edit your question - I will edit my answer to reflect your question